# When is the best time to see live jazz in Europe?

Tags: international-travel, music

I'm planning a trip to Europe for 3 weeks next year (looking at April/May currently), and the goal of my trip is to see as many jazz shows as I possibly can.

I'm planning on visiting:

- UK
- Germany
- Netherlands
- Czech Republic
- France
- Sweden

Possibly others, too...

Are there lots of festivals happening around this time typically, or at least lots of clubs hosting artists?

Comment: The [Edinburgh Jazz & Blues Festival](http://www.edinburghjazzfestival.com) is on from the 13th to the 22nd of July 2018. There are usually a lot of shows on during that week.

Comment: I'd google "jazz festival" in the cities/places your are wanting to go and look at the offerings.

Comment: The "Jazzwoche Burghausen" in 2018 will be from 6th to 11th of March.

Answer (score 1):

One of the biggest in the Netherlands is Breda Jazz Festival.

https://www.bredajazzfestival.nl/

Next year it is set for 10 may 2018 until the 13 of may